# On scroll animations not firing when page loads from specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm using jQuery to animate the divs on my page when they are in view. To do this I'm using this code:

```
var $window = $(window);

// Scrolling animations //

function check_if_in_view() {

  var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');

  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');


$(document).ready(function() {
  check_if_in_view();
});
```

This works great when you load the page from the top. However, if you scroll down the page, click a link and then go back to the previous page, the page begins where you left it and the divs aren't appearing.

Is there anyway I can modify this code so when the page loads if the divs have been scrolled past then they appear?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Use JQuery's $(document).ready and call your function

Comment: I tried this before and I didn't work but just tried again and working! Must've been cached. Cheers mate

Comment: Actually, It doesn't work I scrolled by accident :(

Comment: you are setting your variable, $animation_elements, at the top of your script, set its value in $(document).ready so that the page has fully rendered.

Comment: hey mate, I tried adding what you suggested but still no luck :( I've updated my question so you can the recent code

Comment: have you used the dev tools in your browser to debug your code?

Comment: It says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $window is not defined' should I move this back out of the function?

Comment: Yes, move the declaration of $window outside your function.

Comment: Hey mate, this still isn't working. Please see updated code to see where I am going wrong. There's no errors in the console...

Comment: Can you tell me what it is that is not working?